# Conway's Game of Life in J

Tags: game-of-life, j

I have the following code which produces successive generations of Conway's Game of Life:

```
life =: 3 : '+./ (>(($ y) $ 1);y) *. > =&(+/ (>,{ ;~(1 0 _1))|. y) each 3 4'
```

Usage:

```
RR =: 5 7 $ 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

NB. First five gens of RR
life^:(i.5) RR

NB. in ASCII
' *' {~ life^:(i.5) RR
```

Explanation of code:

```
>,{ ;~(1 0 _1)
```

Produces all possible 1 rotations of a matrix y.

```
|. y
```

Applies 1 rotations to y

```
+/
```

Adds all 1 rotations leading to neighbor-count for each cell

```
=&
```

Creates a monadic function which takes a single number and compares it to the neighbor-counts

```
each 3 4
```

Applies the function to 3 and 4 to find cells with 3 or 4 surrounding cells including self alive.

```
>
```

Unboxes to apply bitwise and

```
(>(($ y) $ 1);y)
```

I want all cells that correspond to `3 (($ y) $ 1)` and only the cells that are already currently living the correspond to `4 (y)`.

```
+./
```

Or the result together to produce the next generation.

I would like to know if there's a better way to do this and shorten code. A lot of the things I did seem very hacky.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Thanks for including the explanations with your code.

Comment: _Shorter_ code isn't necessarily _better_ code.  If that really is your main concern, you may be more interested in [codegolf.se] - but read their How To Ask, and use the Sandbox rather than posting blind!

Answer (score 1):

I have written APL code on VM/CMS and in DEC's VAX-11 interpreter.

No, I don't see a better way that would shorten the code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a J newbie myself, but how about:

```
life =: 3 : '+./ (>(($ y) $ 1);y) *. 3 4 =/ +/ (>,{ ;~(1 0 _1))|. y'
```

This avoids the box-unbox step caused by using `each`, and uses fewer chars.